# Why does my C++ program only output one line into a csv file?

Tags: c++, csv

I recently wrote a program that needs to output some information into a csv file. For this example, it's 3 rows, 5 columns. Nothing very complicated. I have a for loop iterating over a map of objects, but that doesn't seem to work properly. It inserts one row into the file instead of the 3 it's supposed to be outputting.

Here is my code:

Iterating over the objects in main:

```
std::map<std::string, Customer>::iterator itr_3;
    for(itr_3 = customers.begin(); itr_3 != customers.end(); itr_3++){
        itr_3->second.outputCSVFile();
    }
```

Method that outputs to CSV file:

```
void Customer::outputCSVFile(){
    std::ofstream outputFile;
    outputFile.open("output.csv");
    
    // iterate over the years
    std::map<int, std::map<int, std::vector<int> > >::iterator itr;
    for(itr = monthly_records.begin(); itr != monthly_records.end(); ++itr){
        //iterate over the months
        std::map<int, std::vector<int> >::iterator itr_2;
        for(itr_2 = itr->second.begin(); itr_2 != itr->second.end(); ++itr_2){
            if(itr_2->second[0] != 0){
                outputFile << this->getID() << ",";
                outputFile << itr_2->first << "/" << itr->first << ",";
                outputFile << itr_2->second[0] << ",";
                outputFile << itr_2->second[1] << ",";
                outputFile << itr_2->second[2] << "," << '\n';
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Current output:
[Current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUZVs.png)
Necessary Output:
[Necessary output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msKwo.png)
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Every call to the `outputCSVFile` method will overwrite the file. You should rework how you're dealing with the files. I suggest you change it to `outputCSV(std::ostream&)` and pass it a stream (file or otherwise). That would be more flexible, and also solve your problem.

Comment: Works! I put `std::ostream` in the method declaration and moved the declaration of `outputFile` to before the for loop calling the outputCSVFile() method. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Great. Just as a future pointer, you can work on developing your approach to troubleshooting. You assume here that "only one line" is output, without realizing the file is repeatedly overwritten with each line. Some basic debugging would have identified that as the cause, and you probably would have solved it on your own without needing to ask a question. Happy coding!

Comment: Your early questions here should be treated like they're made of gold. Ask too many questions that are not seen as useful to other askers in the future and you'll find that the server stops accepting new questions. It tracks all of your questions, so deleting questions won't help restore your access, only asking useful new questions will and that's hard to do when the server will only accept one new question every six months.  Debug and research carefully before asking and you'll do fine. Ask a question at the first hint of a problem, and you'll quickly dig a hole you can't get out of.